# how to handle local video files Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need some help to handle local video files in reactjs... can't resolve ./assets/video.mp4 error... tried every possible direction..

the idea behind this is to make a full screen video like https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fullscreen_video.asp
but with Reactjs.

video.js

```
       import React from 'react';

       class Video extends React.Component {
       render(){
          return(
             <div className="myVideo">
                 <video controls autostart autoPlay src={this.props.src} type={this.props.type}/>
            </div>
             )
           }
         }

         export default Video;
```

index.js

```
      import React,{Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Video from './video';
import Robin from './assets/Robin.mp4'

const VIDEO = {
  src:Robin,
  type:'video/mp4'
 };

class App extends Component {
   constructor(props){
     super(props)
     this.state = {
       src: VIDEO.src,
       type:VIDEO.type
     }
   }

   render(){
     return(
       <div>
         <Video src={this.state.src} type={this.state.type}/>
       </div>
     )
   }

}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

console error:

> ./src/index.js Module not found: Can't resolve './assets/*.mp4' in
> 'C:\Users\sanjs\Desktop\landing-video\src'

Comment: is `assets` a sub-folder of `landing-video/src` or a sub-folder of `landing-video`? If the latter, you may need `../assets` instead of `./assets`

Comment: assets is a sub-folder of landing-video/src..  if I remove the import Robin from './assets/Robin.mp4' and just pass the direction in the object VIDEO the console doesnt throw any error...but the video does not reproduce...so I wonder if the file can be handle localy...because I allready have a video app but I trated the files with urls https...I'm lost I don't know what is going on

Answer (score 19):

1. Create a **`custom.d.ts`** in your src directory
2. Paste this code in that file

```js
declare module '*.mp4' {
  const src: string;
  export default src;
}
```

That should work!

Comment: If you use typescript, this is what you came here for.

Comment: Step 1 is redundant. TypeScript type declarations can be added directly to "react-app-env.d.ts" file

Comment: As long the solution works, i will say Okay :))

Comment: @SputnikHemp that is true if you're using Create React App. If using Create React App, creating a custom.d.ts didn't work for me. Only adding it into react-app-env.d.ts had any effect.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you have some spelling mistake here is a code for import local video  and it just works fine

```
  import React from "react";
  import "./App.css";
  import Video from "./video.mp4";

  function App() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <video controls autostart autoPlay src={Video} type="video/mp4" />
      </div>
    );
  }

  export default App;
```

I imported my video file at the same directory of app.js. Maybe this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

solved! the problem was that the filename 'Robin .mp4' and I imported as ''Robin.mp4" so I changed de filename to 'Robin.mp4' and that's it.