Can't resolve module in React.js
I m new to React and am uncertain as to why I keep running into this error.
I've looked into it several times and am not sure what I m doing wrong with my import statement
(https://i.sstatic.net/GPtZ78TQ.png)]
(https://i.sstatic.net/koARv3b8.png)
I tried moving everything to the root folder and I know it works there

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55979583/how-to-handle-local-video-files-reactjs

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The import statement is not correct. Since the HomePage.js is inside the HomePage folder using ./ you can only go up one directory from the current file. In this case, you can go only up to HomePage directory. Make sure to use the correct path to solve this problem.
